# Double size of dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I'm really not sure why this is not working. It is like the array size is not doubling. I'm sure what I'm missing is something simple, but I can't figure out why it is not functioning properly.

```
void add_element(int* &array, int &size , int &count)
{
    int tempp;
    cout << "What number do you want to add ? " << endl;
    cin >> tempp;
    int temp = size * 2;
    int *newArr;
    newArr = new int[temp];
    if(count ==  size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            newArr[i] = array[i];

        }
        size = temp;
        delete[] array;

        ++count;
        newArr[count] = tempp;

        array = newArr;
    }
}
```

Comment: *is like the array size is not doubling* --  How do you know the array size is not doubling?  Please post  [mcve].

Comment: What behaviour do you observe? What do you expect instead? "I think it is not working" is not a good problem description.

Comment: if (count == size) ... shouldnt it be if (count < size) ? also you need an else case to handle if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not implemented correctly, not even close.

You should not be allocating a new array every time the function is called, only when the current array is not large enough to store the user's number.

If `count` and `size` are not the same value, you are leaking memory, and you are not inserting anything into the existing array.

You are touching the array only if `count` and `size` are the same value, but when you go to store the user's number into the new array, you are storing it at the wrong index.

Try this instead:

```
void add_element(int* &array, int &size, int &count)
{
    int number;
    cout << "What number do you want to add? " << endl;
    cin >> number;
    if (count == size)
    {
        int newSize = size * 2;
        int *newArr = new int[newSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            newArr[i] = array[i];
        }
        delete[] array;
        array = newArr;
        size = newSize;
    }
    array[count] = number;
    ++count;
}
```