# Appending a dynamic array and doubling its size upon completion

Tags: c++, dynamic

Create a dynamic array of int with a initial space of 4. Write a function ‘append’ that appends a given value to this array. At any stage, if this function finds the array full it automatically doubles the size of array to accommodate this new value. Also write a function to display all the elements of this array. Write a main to test all these functions.

I made an attempt to solve the above question as given below. However, I am unable to get the correct code. Please help me

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void append(int*& array, int val, int n, int r)
{
int i,p;
int *array1;
for (i=r;i<n;i++)
array[i] = val;
if(i==n)
{
 p = 2*n;
 array1 = new int [p];
}
for(int j =0; j<r/2; j++)
 array1[j]= array[j];
 append(array1, val, p, p/2);
}



int main()
 {
  int q,p=0,val, n = 4;
 int n1 = p/2;
 int *array = new int[n];
  while(1)
{
cout<<"Enter 0 to end and 1 to continue";
cin>>q;
 while(q!=0)
 {
cin>>val;
append(array,val,n,n1);

  }

  }


 return 0;
}
```

I need to solve this without using "Classes". How shall I do it?

Comment: `while (q != 0)` cannot exit. Nothing in the body of the loop changes the value of `q`.

Comment: ```int n1 = p/2``` will always equal zero, as ```int q,p=0...```. It looks like ```main``` is supposed to be keeping track of (1) the current size of the array and (2) the number of values entered.  You probably want the function to return the size of the array after every call.

Comment: Your `append()` function is infinitely recursive, since it always calls itself (no conditions in which it doesn't call itself).   It shouldn't need to be recursive at all.

Comment: Given *given value to this array* why is append adding the value more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking cue from [Double size of dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50902174/double-size-of-dynamic-array) I have solved it.

```
 #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;


  void add_element(int* &array, int &size)
  {int count = 0;

while(1)
{

int number;
cout << "What number do you want to add? " << endl;
cin >> number;
if (count == size)
{
    int newSize = size * 2;
    int *newArr = new int[newSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        newArr[i] = array[i];
    }
    delete[] array;
    array = newArr;
    size = newSize;
}
  array[count] = number;
  ++count;
   int k;
  cout<<"Do u want to end, then press 0";
cin>>k;
if(k==0) break;
   }
 for(int g = 0; g<count; g++)
  cout<<array[g]<<'\t';
}

 int main()
  {
 int i,j,k,size;
   cin>>size;
  int* array = new int [size];

add_element(array, size);


 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function needs to do the following:
1) Be able to check if the current append call will result in an out-of-bounds write attempt. So you need something like (and give variables explanatory names like this) this as the first line in your function:

```
if (array_size < item_count) {
    //double size of array
}
```

To double the size of the array, you have to make a new array with twice the size, copy all the items over from the old array, DELETE the old array, null the old array's pointer, and somehow update the array_size variable (return to main is one option, a static int counter in the function itself is another). You may have to return a pointer to the new array to main, as well. Or maybe you can just re-address the old pointer to the new array AFTER using that pointer to delete the old array. This is all about avoiding memory leaks. So, try to come up with a method declaration like:

```
int append(int* arrPtr, int value, int array_size, int item_count)
```

This particular approach means main is getting sent back the array size as an int after each append. So you need something in main like:

```
array_size = append(array, val, array_size, item_count);
```

The tricky part will be when you make the new array:

```
array_size = 2 * array_size;
int* temp = new int[array_size]
//copy everything over from old array to new using arrPtr and temp
for (int i = 0; i < array_size / 2; i++) {
    temp[i] = arrPtr[i]
}
//delete the contents of the old array:
delete[] arrPtr;
//pointer gymnastics to redirect arrPtr to the new array:
arrPtr = temp;
temp = nullptr;
//okay, now you are back out of the conditional and can use item_count to insert the 
//value into the array (doubled or not)
arrPtr[item_count] = value;
//don't forget to return array_size, and remember main must track item_count as well.
return array_size;
```

That's the general gist of it. This is not a complete answer, but should give you enough to work with. Basically, most of your code has to be rewritten, and the above is not a complete solution. Good luck.

Comment: Oh right, thanks. I've been using arrays of pointers lately, ye gods.  I think the other one was off too.